# Specializing template for enum

Tags: c++, templates

Could anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
enum CompCriteria{ByKey,ByValue,ByeKeyAndValue};

template<class T>
struct X;

template<>
struct X<CompCriteria>
{
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    X<CompCriteria::ByeKeyAndValue> x;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specialized `X` for a type, but you're trying to use it with the integer `CompCriteria::ByeKeyAndValue`.

You can specialize template class for the `enum CompCriteria` underlying type - `int` in this case, as follows:

```
enum CompCriteria{ByKey,ByValue,ByeKeyAndValue};

template<int>
struct X;

template<>
struct X<ByeKeyAndValue>
{
};

int main()
{
    X<ByeKeyAndValue> x;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You're conflating the idea of parameterized *types* and parameterized *values*.  A template parameter can be a type, or a constant.  For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo;
```

versus..

```
template <int N>
struct Foo;
```

It looks like you want to specialize your template based on an enum *constant*, rather than a type.  Meaning, you need to say:

```
enum CompCriteria{ByKey,ByValue,ByeKeyAndValue};

template<CompCriteria>
struct X;

// Specialization for ByKeyAndValue
//
template<>
struct X<ByeKeyAndValue>
{
};

int main()
{
    X<ByeKeyAndValue> x; // instantiate specialization 
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you can't refer to enums using the `namespace` operator.  If you want to encapsulate your enums, you need to wrap them in a namespace:

```
namespace CompCriteria
{
   enum type {ByKey,ByValue,ByeKeyAndValue};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `template<class T>` = `template<typename T>`, then T is expected to be, well, a **type**.

`enum CompCriteria` is a type, so you can instantiate that template with it. A single value of the enum, however, is not a type, so you can't.

Answer (score 2):

```
enum CompCriteria{ByKey,ByValue,ByeKeyAndValue};

template<CompCriteria crit_>
struct X
{
    static const CompCriteria crit = crit_;
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    X<CompCriteria::ByeKeyAndValue> x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Someone_who_downwoted why what's wrong with this answer? At least have guts and explain why you've downvoted this answer. +1 from me for I find this answer helpful and AFAIC it is what I wanted.

Comment: thank you for your answer - I've tried it and it's exactly what I wanted. Big thanks.

Comment: @Alexey Malistov Thank you for the answer. really helpful.. up-voted.Can you please mention this line - template<CompCriteria crit_> what c++ template rule behind this?